# Laptop won't connect to Ethernet after configuring it for Broadband BSNL

Tags: 11.04, broadband, ethernet

I recently went to India and over there I had to configure my laptop to use Broadband internet. So I followed a guide similar to [this one](http://www.indiabroadband.net/linux/10828-how-configure-bsnl-broadband-connection-ubuntu.html). Everything worked fine and I was able to get online, however, when I came back to states my ethernet connection does not work anymore. When I simply plug-in the ethernet cable, the light blinks but nothing happens on the laptop. My wireless still works.

Is there a way to reset my ethernet settings back as they were when I first installed ubuntu so that everything works as desired?

Comment: Have you tried the answers below? Did they help solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the screen-by-screen settings for a default ethernet connection. If you see something different (other than the MAC address), consider changing it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you click the Routes button on the IPv4 screen, it should be empty like so:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to edit connections
in the wired tab, delete any existing connections also delete any other connections in the DSL.

reconnect ur ethernet and you are done!